# Flutter cache and retrieve images in same widget, is it possible?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hei!
I have a quiz app that shows a list of active games. This list also shows the opponents profile image. The list is a stream from firestore.

Everytime the user changes to another screen and back to the gamelist the images are downloaded again..this uses alot of network traffic.

I cant put the images in cache when the app starts as i dont know what games the player have, and they are changing. Is there a way to get the image from url , put it in cache, and IF its in cache , use that image..in the same widget?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package is what you need.

Comment: Yeah i tried that..but does seem to download each time anyway.. Will cache image download from the internett first time, then the next time the widget is buildt, use that image? Or does it need images put into the cache beforhand?

Comment: Do you try it on web or mobile apps? Because it does not have support for the web. It may seem like downloading each time because of retrieval from the cache.

Comment: Im just doing ios/android app. Yeah you might be right, but then retrieval from cache sure is slow..

I thought i had to create a cache and put images there, then load them... Anyone with good knowlede of this package here that can answer?

Comment: I did a test now, using flutter dev tools. No requests are showing when going to the game list again and again. If a change a avatar, then a request shows. So the package seems to be working, its just really slow to fetch from cache... anyone to improve the speed?hmm

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a suggestion for speed improvement but, you are working on an emulator right? It might be so much faster on a real device.

Comment: No, not faster om real device..im also questioning the caching. I have avatar images..when i change the image on firebase, still same name, the image immediately changes in that app. That should not happen if it was really caching..